# Equivalent of `btrfs send` and `btrfs recv` for bcachefs

Tags: filesystems, backup, btrfs, bcache, bcachefs

I'm using a setup I consider to be rather fragile and prone to failure involving LUKS, LVM, btrfs, and bcache. I have used btrfs for a long time, and have never experienced any significant issues with it. But, it doesn't support caching, nor does it handle erasure coding (i.e. RAID5 or 6 style redundancy).

I consider it prone to failure especially when trying to install a new version of my distribution, since it involves a setup that I suspect is very much an outlier, and not accounted for in any kind of testing for upgrade procedures, or any kind of installation of a new system while preserving most of the data from the old one.

I would like to move to bcachefs, but I can't tell whether or not it supports, or intends to support anything like `btrfs send` and `btrfs recv`. These two commands are critical to my incremental backup strategy.

Does it support anything like this now in November of 2023? Will it ever?

Comment: The main author is aware this is needed: https://bcachefs.org/Roadmap/#Send_and_receive

Comment: @A.B - That sounds like the skeleton of an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [roadmap for *bcachefs*](https://bcachefs.org/Roadmap/) mentions it:

> [Send and receive](https://bcachefs.org/Roadmap/#Send_and_receive):
>
> Like ZFS and btrfs have, we need it to. This will give us the ability
> to efficiently synchronize filesystems over a network for
> backup/redundancy purposes - much more efficient than rsync, and it'll
> pair well with snapshots.
>
> Since all metadata exists as btree keys, this won't be a huge amount
> of work to implement: we need a network protocol, and then we need to
> scan and send for keys newer than version number X (if making use of
> key version numbers), or keys newer than a given snapshot ID.

Since it's in the roadmap, this means it's not implemented yet, but there are plans for it in the future (no date).